# zmq.Context() hangs a few minutes after boot

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, zeromq, pyzmq

In a very Minimal non-Working Example I do:

```
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
```

or `python3 -c "import zmq; ctx = zmq.Context()"`, respectively.

When my machine has ran a few minutes this works well. However, right after the boot (around 2 minutes) it doesn't. It simply blocks and is uninterruptible (even `Ctrl+C` is not working).

Any ideas which conflict could be appear during these first minutes of machine uptime?

Info: libzmq5 version is 4.2.5 and pyzmq 17.0.0.

Edit: The same behavior with the [C example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:hwclient).

Edit2: Thanks to `strace`, I know that it hangs on the system call `getrandom(`. As I learned right know, it seems to request from `/dev/random` which has not obtained sufficient entropy instead of using `/dev/urandom`. Indeed, `cat /dev/random` blocks as well while `cat /dev/urandom` doesn't.

Comment: Opened issue on GitHub: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/3183

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it actually hangs there? I have the same problem but I always thought it hangs when doing the first connection with crypto.

The problem is that at boot the kernel has no entropy and reading from /dev/random or /dev/urandom hangs. You need to create some entropy at boot before using zmq. Normally a random seed is stored at shutdown and used to seed the entropy at boot. Make sure that happened before you use zmq and that it worked.

In my case I had to add entropy to the system using havegd.

Note: the entropy has to be there before zmq is started. Don't ask me why. I'm interested in knowing that too.

Comment: It hung definitely at `zmq.Context()`, the MWE calls nothing else. Thus, there is no crypto etc. involved.
However, for me it was a kernel issue. After downgrading from `4.16.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.16.16-2 (2018-06-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux` to `4.16.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.16.5-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux` it works as expected.